# Android - images not loading in picasso

Tags: android

I am trying to get some image urls from an online database and show them in a picasso gallery. My problem is that my images are not loading. I get the border of the images but they are empty (nothing is showing)

Here is my code so far:

**MainActivity**

```
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                gridView1 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
                image_urls = new ArrayList<>();
                if (gridView1.getChildCount() != 0 || image_urls != null) {
                    gridView1.setAdapter(null);
                }
                if (image_urls.isEmpty()) {
                    getImages();
                }
        }
        // getting the image URLs from database
        protected void showList() {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            photos = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

            for (int i = 0; i < photos.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = photos.getJSONObject(i);
                String email_user = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL_USER);
                String poi_name = c.getString(TAG_POI_NAME);
                String photo_url = c.getString(TAG_PHOTO_URL);

                if (poi_name.contains(map.markerdesc) && photo_url!=null) {
                   // add to the picasso gallery
                    photo_url="http://xxxxx.ro/poi/photos/"+photo_url;
                   image_urls.add(photo_url);
                }

            }
            final ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            gridView1.setAdapter(adapter);

            gridView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(poi_photos.this, ImageActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("url", adapter.imageUrls.get(position));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void getImages() {
        class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxxxxx.ro/poi/table_photo_out.php");

                // Depends on your web service
                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = null;
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    // json is UTF-8 by default
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Oops
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
                    } catch (Exception squish) {
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                myJSON = result;
                showList();
            }
        }
        GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
        g.execute();
    }
```

**ImageAdapter**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;


    public ArrayList<String> imageUrls = poi_photos.image_urls;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.findViewsIn(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.updateWith(imageUrls.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder{
        private ImageView imageView;

        public void findViewsIn(View convertView) {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = imageView.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = getItemWidth();
            layoutParams.width = getItemWidth();
            imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }

        public void updateWith(String imageUrl) {
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(imageUrl)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.rectangle)
                    .resize(getItemWidth(), getItemWidth())
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(imageView);
        }

        private int getItemWidth(){
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            Point point = new Point();
            display.getSize(point);
            return point.x / context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.numColumns); // screen width / numColumns;
        }
    }
}
```

**ImageActivity**

```
public class ImageActivity extends Activity {

    private Target target;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image);

        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        target = new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                Palette.generateAsync(bitmap, new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
                    public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        int defaultColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.Blonde);
                        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(palette.getLightVibrantColor(defaultColor));
                        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(palette.getDarkMutedColor(defaultColor));
                        toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

            }
        };
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(getIntent().getStringExtra("url"))
                .into(target);
    }
}
```

Any ideas what might be wrong here?
I'm using picasso library version 2.5.2
Any help would be highly appreciated!

**EDIT**: 
I found out it works if I use an array of strings instead of an arraylist (dunno why) but it only works if I send it the urls like this:

```
public String[] imageUrls = {
            "http://forum.wexphotographic.com/pictures%5Cbaby%20owl.jpg",
            "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/db/b2/4f/dbb24f70f9e9f6d95e0e103e5b5f16f7.jpg",
            "http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/articles/baby-animals/Baby-Animals-011.jpg",
            "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/04/c6/3d/04c63d072e52affb09f4549298b754e6.jpg",
            "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/4a/65/e1/4a65e1f4d7c72ecca33b01ce3306964f.jpg",
            "http://pcwallart.com/images/cute-golden-retriever-puppies-wallpaper-1.jpg",
    };
```

if I convert my arrayList into the string array my photos aren't uploading either

```
  public String[] imageUrls = poi_photos.image_urls.toArray(new String[poi_photos.image_urls.size()]);
```

**EDIT2**:
Found out what my problem was...I was sending my URLs incorrectly...some of them contained spaces so I just modified this part:

```
 public void updateWith(String imageUrl) {
            imageUrl = imageUrl.replace(" ", "%20");
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(imageUrl)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.rectangle)
                    .resize(getItemWidth(), getItemWidth())
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(imageView);
        }
```

now it works perfectly!

Comment: I have similar issue, and didn't solve it yet. Images arent loading 50% of time yet url is provided

Comment: On thing you can do to track down the error is loading the images into a `Target` instead of directly into an `ImageView` 
That way you will have a callback for errors you can debug and inspect

Comment: Have you printed the `getIntent().getStringExtra("url")` to make sure that the url data are not corrupted?

Comment: I found out what the problem was...it involved how I was sending my URLs (some of them contained blank spaces so I replaced all of them with  "%20") now it works perfectly
Thank you for all the suggestions!

Comment: use this to decode the urls in java...URLDecoder.decode(stingvalue, "UTF-8");